# Laravel Rule Validation for Minimum and Maximum Salary

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following rules.

```
  $rules['min_salary']  = 'required|not_in:0|numeric';
  $rules['max_salary']  = 'required|not_in:0|numeric';
```

How to have the rule that min_salary is less than or equal to max_salary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new rule

```
php artisan make:rule SalaryRule
```

Add the rule to your validation

```
$rules['min_salary']  = ['required', 'not_in:0', 'numeric', new SalaryRule($request->max_salary)];
$rules['max_salary']  = 'required|not_in:0|numeric';
```

If you are using a `FormRequest` you could access `max_salary` as `$this->max_salary`

Make sure to import the rule in your code

```
use App\Rules\SalaryRule;
```

and in the `passes` method of the Rule you could write your logic

```
public function passes($attribute, $value)
{
    return $value <= $this->max_salary;
}
```

and create a property `max_salary` and initialize it in the rule's constructor method as you are passing the `max_salary` in the constructor.

```
protected $max_salary;

public function __construct($max_salary)
{
    $this->max_salary = $max_salary;
}
```